# 1 to N column and row sums

Tags: code-golf, number, binary-matrix

## Inspiration

There is a problem on the most recent AMC 12B test, the one held on November 16, 2022, which goes like this:

> (AMC 12B 2022, Question 17)
> How many \$4\times4\$ arrays whose entries are \$0\$s and \$1\$s are there such that the row sums (the sum of the entries in each row) are \$1\$, \$2\$, \$3\$, and \$4\$, in some order, and the column sums (the sum of the entries in each column) are also \$1\$, \$2\$, \$3\$, and \$4\$, in some order? For example, the array
> $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\1&1&1&1\\0&1&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$satisfies the condition.

<sub><sub>(If any of you are curious the answer is \$576\$.)</sub></sub>

## Task

Your task is, given some positive integer \$N\$, output all \$N\times N\$ binary matrices such that the row sums are \$1,2,\ldots,N\$ in some order, as well as the column sums.

## Test Cases

```
N ->
Output
-------
1 ->
1

2 ->
1 1
1 0

1 1
0 1

1 0
1 1

0 1
1 1

3 ->
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 1 1

1 0 0
1 0 1
1 1 1

0 1 0
1 1 0
1 1 1

0 1 0
0 1 1
1 1 1

0 0 1
1 0 1
1 1 1

0 0 1
0 1 1
1 1 1

1 0 0
1 1 1
1 1 0

1 0 0
1 1 1
1 0 1

0 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 0

0 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 1

0 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 1

0 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 1

1 1 0
1 0 0
1 1 1

1 1 0
0 1 0
1 1 1

1 0 1
1 0 0
1 1 1

1 0 1
0 0 1
1 1 1

0 1 1
0 1 0
1 1 1

0 1 1
0 0 1
1 1 1

1 1 0
1 1 1
1 0 0

1 1 0
1 1 1
0 1 0

1 0 1
1 1 1
1 0 0

1 0 1
1 1 1
0 0 1

0 1 1
1 1 1
0 1 0

0 1 1
1 1 1
0 0 1

1 1 1
1 0 0
1 1 0

1 1 1
1 0 0
1 0 1

1 1 1
0 1 0
1 1 0

1 1 1
0 1 0
0 1 1

1 1 1
0 0 1
1 0 1

1 1 1
0 0 1
0 1 1

1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 0

1 1 1
1 1 0
0 1 0

1 1 1
1 0 1
1 0 0

1 1 1
1 0 1
0 0 1

1 1 1
0 1 1
0 1 0

1 1 1
0 1 1
0 0 1
```

## Note

The reason why I'm not doing a challenge on simply outputting the number of matrices that satisfy the condition is because there is a pretty simple formula to calculate that number. Brownie points if you can figure out that formula, and why it works!

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest code in bytes wins!

Comment: For any \$N\$, there is only one possible \$N × N\$ matrix in which the sum of the first row is 1, the sum of the second row is 2, the sum of the first column is \$N\$, the sum of the first column is \$N-1\$, etc. (In this matrix a right triangular shape should be formed). From here you can allow different orders of the rows by multiplying by \$N!\$ and then again for the columns to get the final formula \$N!^2\$.

Comment: @Yousername Nice, that's the formula I had in mind as well.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!cþþ`ẎṠ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a positive integer and yields a list of the binary matrices.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//xZIhY8O@w75g4bqO4bmg/8OHR@KCrGrigb7CtsK2//8y)**

#### How?

We can first arrange the set of \$N\$ *sorted* rows any way we like leading to \$N!\$ matrices with sorted rows. Each of these matrices will have column sums from \$1\$ through to \$N\$ *in order*, so all column-wise permutations will be distinct, so there are \$N!^2\$ such matrices.

We can create these matrices by noting that each number in the set \$[1,N]\$ is greater than or equal to exactly \$N\$ of the elements in the set (including itself).

Thus a table of \$\geq\$ between two permutations of the first \$N\$ natural numbers is such a table, e.g.:

| \$\geq\$ | 1 | 3 | 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

Where one permutation defines the column sums (directly - i.e. \$\{1,3,2\}\$, above) and the other defines the row sums (in reverse order - i.e. \$\{3,2,1\}\$, above, defines the sums \$\{1,2,3\}\$)

```
Œ!cþþ`ẎṠ - Link: integer, N
Œ!       - all permutations (of [1..N])
     `   - use as both arguments of:
    þ    -   table of:
   þ     -     table of:
  c      -       n-choose-k (a golf to get a positive integer when n>=k else 0)
      Ẏ  - tighten to a list of the sub-tables
       Ṡ - sign (convert the positives to ones)
```

Answer (score 7):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```apl
{{~⍉¨⍵∘.⍀⍨↓∘.≠⍨⍳1+≢⊃⍵}⍣2⍣⍵⊂0 0⍴⍬}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v8/7VHbhOrquke9nYdWPOrd@qhjht6j3oZHvSsetU0GczoXgDi9mw21H3UuetTVDFRU@6h3sREQg9R3NRkoGDzq3fKod03t/0d9U4HGpSkYcsFYRnCW8X8A)

Returns an array of boxed matrices. +1 for a flat structure by putting `,` somewhere in the first few characters.

Illustrates another way to get \$f(N)=N!^2\$: 
For each \$N\times N\$ matrix that satisfies this property, we can invert 0s and 1s, then insert a row and column of 1s to get a \$(N+1)\times(N+1)\$ matrix that also has this property. Furthermore, each such resulting matrix is uniquely determined by predecessor, row, and column. Since there are \$N+1\$ positions in which a row or column can be inserted, \$f(N+1)=(N+1)^2f(N)\$, and \$f(0)=1\$ (one empty matrix) completes the induction.

```apl
base 0x0 matrix                                  ⊂0 0⍴⍬
⍵ times:                {                   }  ⍣⍵
  1...N+1                             ⍳1+≢⊃⍵
  N+1 row inserts           ⍵∘.⍀⍨↓∘.≠⍨
  N+1 column inserts      ⍉¨                 ⍣2
  invert                 ~
```

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <sup>27</sup> 22 bytes

```
i.@!([A."1"{A.)>:/~@i.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/pvqWhlGGumaGWprs6lpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/M/UcFDWiHfWUDJWqHfU07az06xwy9f5rcvk56SmAJR311PRqrOpAbE0HRz2oCq7U5Ix8hTQF4/8A)

*-5 thanks to ovs!*

Create the "step" matrix, get all row permutations, then to each of those apply all permutations again, but to each row at the same time -- this is equivalent to applying it to the columns.

Comment: `&.|:` -> `"1` for -2. And `([A."1"0 3 A.)` would work as well, but doesn't save bytes

Comment: Thanks.  That insight is worth even more because `"1"{` does save bytes.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 11 bytes

```
ɾ:v≤Ṗv∩vṖÞf
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCLJvjp24omk4bmWduKIqXbhuZbDnmYiLCJ24oGLwrZkaiIsIjMiXQ==)

```
ɾ           # Push range(1, n+1)
  v         # Over each...
ɾ: ≤        # Check if it's less than each of range(1, n+1)
    Ṗ       # Get all permutations
     v∩     # Transpose each
       vṖ   # Get permutations of each
         Þf # Flatten by one layer
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org) + NumPy, 94 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
f=lambda n,p=0:1//n*[e:=eye(n)]or[1-w.T@e[j]for j in e<1for w in f(n+p,~p)]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY349KK8nMV8kpzCyoVMnML8otKtLjSbHMSc5NSEhXydApsDawM9fXztKJTrWxTK1M18jRj84uiDXXL9UIcUqOzYtPyixSyFDLzFFJtDEHschA7TSNPu0CnrkAzFmqLSUFRZl6JRpqGoaYmF4xthMQ2hrNzUvOAfBNNTU2IXphLAQ)

Same logic as before but implemented in matrix algebra avoiding he expensive `insert`.

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + NumPy, 96 bytes (@att)

```python
from numpy import*
f=lambda n,p=0:[insert(w,i,1+p,p)for i in r_[:n]for w in f(n+p,~p)]or[eye(0)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYm9CsIwEID3PsWNiWZorS6FPkkIUjHBg@ZyXCOli68em0ERt@@Ht/xI1JcSJEWgZ@QNMHKSfGjCOE/xdp@ADI/tYJEWL1mtBk13ZMM6JAEEJJCrHchVXasGRft/sXZJrN@8arUrLEhZBdVp3Xz49MP9l2dPu5/1X7jUUN4)

#### [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + NumPy, 99 bytes

```python
from numpy import*
f=lambda n,p=1:[insert(w,i,p,p)for i in r_[:n+1-p]for w in f(n-p,1-p)]or[eye(0)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XchBCsIwEEDRfU@RZUZTMFY3hZ4kBKmYYKCZDNNIyeljs1DE3f@PSn4mHGr1nKLAV6QiQqTE@dD5aZnj/TELVDTp0QRcHWe5qaBIEfjEIoiAgm9mxKPuyTbaGnmJPamdwCY2rjh5AluJA2bppQboPn3@6eHbi8P9L/AH1wb1DQ)

This works by alternating between inserting rows of zeros and columns of ones at every possible position.

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYm9CsIwEID3PsWNiWZorS6FPkkIUjHBg@ZyXCOli68em0ERt@@Ht/xI1JcSJEWgZ@QNMHKSfGjCOE/xdp@ADI/tYJEWL1mtBk13ZMM6JAEEJJCrHchVXasGRft/sXZJrN@8arUrLEhZBdVp3Xz49MP9l2dPu5/1X7jUUN4)

Comment: @att Nice! I had a hunch something like this should be possible but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

## [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr), 62 bytes

```
n->forperm(n,p,forperm(n,q,print(matrix(n,n,x,y,p[x]>=q[y]))))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728ILEoMz69YMHiNAXbpaUlaboWN-3ydO3S8osKUotyNfJ0CnQQ7EKdgqLMvBKN3MSSoswKoECeToVOpU5BdEWsnW1hdGWsJhBATFmSpmEMZS5YAKEB)

Let \$p\$ and \$q\$ runs over all permutations of \$1,\dots,n\$. For each \$p\$ and \$q\$, construct an \$n\times n\$ binary matrix where the element at position \$(x,y)\$ (\$1\$-indexed) is \$1\$ if and only if \$p[x]\ge q[y]\$.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html), 8.5 bytes (17 nibbles)

```
+.;``p,$.@.$._`$/
```

Port of [Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254772/95126): upvote that.
Sadly, [Nibbles](http://golfscript.com/nibbles/index.html) comes-out half-a-byte longer.

```
      ,$            # 1..input
   ``p              # get all permutations of that
  ;                 # and save this list of lists
 .                  # now map over each list
        .@          #   mapping over each saved list 
          .$._      #     element-wise mapping over each x,y
              `$    #       sign of
                /   #       x integer-divided by y
+                   # finally, flatten by one level
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 132 bytes

```javascript
n=>P(n).flatMap(x=>P(n).map(y=>x.map(u=>y.map(v=>u+v<n))))
P=(n,i=n)=>n?i--?[...P(n,i),...P(--n).map(r=>r.splice(i,0,n)&&r)]:[]:[[]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Rc7BCoMwDAbg@57Ck7Zoyw47jaXeB9uEHZ2H0qlUulRaFX16p05YyOFLID9p5CC9crrtGNp3OVcwI4iMIOWVkd1NtmTc58/iCcS4oQcxbRhA9PFwQbrUIQOCiQakIDDVjKU55zxbdzTZxNge5EA47lujVUl0ckyQhqGjxTlfOi@KWVn01pTc2JpU5PQ7GgMQwfX5uHPfOY21riYy/uNWKBCxWn/hjdVIohdGlM5f)

Comment: @Arnauld It should be fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>147</s> 145 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[[k[l]for l in j]for k in i]for j in p(range(n))for i in p([1]*i+[0]*(n-i)for i in range(1,n+1))]
from itertools import*;p=permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctLEsIgDIDhfU/BElqdsXan05MgCxxB00LC0Ljw9NiHju6@/EnSix@EXfH9pQQbrzcr8KS1HnUwnrIIAlAMK8eFsHJYmGS2eHcSlVoabE23poZGH0wtcQ@/zXbb7rBplTKVzxQFsMtMFCYBMVHm@pz65HJ8smUgnErKgCy9nF@qr49/7mZ/huBwC6q8AQ)

Based on my comment to this challenge. First generates a right triangular shaped matrix of 1s, then makes all possible different permutations of rows and columns. Outputs a list of 2D lists. -2 bytes thanks to [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan314).

---

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>132</s> <s>121</s> <s>116</s></sup> 115 bytes

```python
lambda n:[[[1-(l>k)for l in j]for k in i]for i,j in product(*[[*permutations(range(n))]]*2)]
from itertools import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tcg9EsIgEEDhPqegBEaLJJ0zehGkQANKArvMZlN4ehR/Zuy@98qD7whjDcdzTS5fJifgYIzp9zKdFhWQRBIRxGwbl8b4ZtzNLQrhtF1ZamN08ZQ3dhwRVkkObl6CUtbqQdkuEGYR2RMjplXEXJBY10IRWAbZK9X9PPx5fPkbycNnqPoE)

Uses the method entailed in [Jonathan Allan's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/254768/1-to-n-column-and-row-sums/254772#254772). -12 bytes thanks to [Mukundan314](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/91267/mukundan314), -5 bytes thanks to [att](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/81203/att).

Comment: [-5](https://tio.run/##Tcg9EoIwEEDh3lOkzDpYAJ0zeBGkiJLoQrKbWZbC00fxZ8buey8/9M7UltCdS3TpMjpDx77v64ONpxkCi4kGyUzDxnkjvonVtEUWHter2uwlreoUmRYrjm7eEkAlPnunXQPDLggng@pFmeNiMGUW3ZcsSGqDrQF2Pzd/bl/@RvT0GVCe) second

Comment: [-1 byte](https://tio.run/##Tcg9EsIgEEDhPqegBEaLJJ0zehGkQANKArvMZlN4ehR/Zuy@98qD7whjDcdzTS5fJifgYIzp9zKdFhWQRBIRxGwbl8b4ZtzNLQrhtF1ZamN08ZQ3dhwRVkkObl6CUtbqQdkuEGYR2RMjplXEXJBY10IRWAbZK9X9PPx5fPkbycNnqPoE) for second answer

Comment: -7 by (slightly ;-P ) rearranging the loop [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TcsxDsIwDIXhvafIaEIHSjeknqR0MJBQS41tuWaAy4fCgHjT/w1Pnz4L9zUP57pgudww8Ok6IzHEggraro72qRdpqwAUx8O05zh2UxYLFIiDId8T8O67JpuUQJ7MRZY1UFExj40Omqw8HJ2E16pG7BAzdNvlh@M/@g31DQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: @loopywalt You can probably post that as a separate response since it seems fairly different in its method.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>125 ...</s> 79 bytes

```ruby
->n{a=*[*1..n].permutation;a.product(a).map{|r,c|r.map{|x|c.map{|y|x>y ?0:1}}}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6vOtFWK1rLUE8vL1avILUot7QksSQzP886Ua@gKD@lNLlEI1FTLzexoLqmSCe5pgjCrKhJhjAqayrsKhXsDawMa4Hgf4FCWrRRLBeIMo79DwA)

Switched to Jonathan Allan's approach.

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 11 bytes

```
>€ḶŒ!Z€Œ!€Ẏ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/uUdOahzu2HZ2kGAVkASkQf1ff////jQE)

Port of my Vyxal.

```
 €          # Over each of...
            # implicit range(1, n+1)
>           # Are they greater than...
  Ḷ         # range(0, n)
   Œ!       # Permutations
     Z€     # Transpose each
       Œ!€  # Permutations of each
          Ẏ # Flatten by one level
```

Comment: [You can remove `R`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/uUdOahzu2HZ2kGAVkASkQf1ff////jQE)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
LœDδδ@€`
```

Port of [*@JonathanAllan*'s Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/254772/52210), so make sure to upvote him as well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5@hkl3Nbzm1xeNS0JuH/fyMA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W/squSZV1BaYqWgZO@nw6XkmFxSmpijkF9aAhP873N0ssu5Lee2ODxqWpPw31YpoCi1pKRSt6AoM68kNQWhVKes8tBunUPb7P8DAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
L         # Push a list in the range [1, (implicit) input]
 œ        # Get all permutations of this list
  D       # Duplicate it
   δ      # Apply double-vectorized:
    δ     #  Apply double-vectorized:
     @    #   a >= b check
      €`  # Then flatten the list of lists of matrices one level down
          # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 146 bytes

This is a naive solution based on bit masks and brute force.

Prints all valid matrices.

```javascript
n=>{for(k=1<<n*n;k--;M+2>>n-~n&&console.log(m))for(M=m=[],y=n;y--;M|=1<<r|1<<c+n)for(m[y]=[c=r=0],x=n;x--;r+=q,c+=k>>x*n+y&1)m[y][x]=q=k>>y*n+x&1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY1BcoMwDEX3nEIrwDGQ0smqRL5BTkBZMC7JEGKZOB7GniS9OrXbLLqR/v96mn/ul/4mzTjbkvTXsG63MDhrepDBwVEbmM1grS9nM5Id6ZRITTcLF30ChKj1ZaiCa5KXCfE9nj9AAYqoclWpfs6XaJfqrEfKM8gYe8lPyhhw@NvPJkmOuBKKeyjPJ6z3e9pQM5Vlc@DvQlD5TWn6rzhXjEX0gArbrvBIjY/wI76aRxiS0y@hWt9hK9HgW1e4wLnAGY7XQnKchHAb4j6tWeRa1@E1hj6ELq2f6zHfsfUH)

#### Commented

```javascript
n => {                      // n = input
  for(                      // first loop:
    k = 1 << n * n;         //   start with k = 2 ** (n * n)
    k--;                    //   decrement until k = 0
    M + 2 >> n - ~n         //   if bits 1 to n * 2 (0-indexed)
    &&                      //   are all set in M:
      console.log(m)        //     print the matrix
  )                         //
    for(                    //   second loop:
      M =                   //     M = bit mask
      m = [],               //     m[] = matrix
      y = n;                //     start with y = n
      y--;                  //     decrement until y = 0
      M |= 1 << r |         //     update the bit mask
           1 << c + n       //     with row and column bits
    )                       //
      for(                  //     third loop:
        m[y] = [c = r = 0], //       initialize m[y], c and r
        x = n;              //       start with x = n
        x--;                //       decrement until x = 0
        r += q,             //       increment r if q is set
        c += k >> x * n + y //       increment c if the cell at
             & 1            //       (y, x) is set
      )                     //
        m[y][x] =           //       set m[y][x] to
        q =                 //       q, defined as
          k >> y * n + x    //       the cell at (x, y)
          & 1               //
}                           //
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 37 bytes

```
≔…⁰Ｎθ⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻θκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＦ⊕υＥυＥι⭆κ›μξ
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY-xCsIwEIZ3n-JwykEEwUXo5CQOSrFj6RBjbEubaJOc-C4uFRR9BR_FtzFBBae7_47v4-78kJWwci_avr-R342mr-fMubo0bC1MqdiYw8IcyK9Ib5RliBw6TAYpuYoRh7wIYbe3wDqEL5iRZktxiOtYlrUhxzoOTWDTNvRN4HSBGGX04xdGWqWV8WrLCBFSWxv_76k5ZD4MyxiCYm6V8OEkzeEUXZhc3Ua67xv3fDg6tsPiMvnkNw) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Based on @Ausername's Vyxal answer.

```
≔…⁰Ｎθ
```

Start with a range from `0` to `N`.

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻θκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

Generate all of the permutations of that range.

```
Ｆ⊕υＥυＥι⭆κ›μξ
```

Generate the comparison matrices between each pair of incremented permutation and permutation.