# Count N-Rich Permutations of an Integer Sequence

Tags: code-golf, permutations, counting

Given a sequence of integers with length \$L\$ and an integer \$1 \le N \le L\$, an "\$N\$-rich" permutation is one whose the longest **strictly** increasing **contiguous** subsequence has length exactly \$N\$.

For example, let our sequence be `[0, 1, 2, 3]`. There is exactly one \$1\$-rich permutation, given by `[3, 2, 1, 0]`. By contrast, there are sixteen \$2\$-rich permutations:

```
[0, 2, 1, 3] [0, 3, 1, 2] [0, 3, 2, 1]
[1, 0, 3, 2] [1, 2, 0, 3] [1, 3, 0, 2] [1, 3, 2, 0]
[2, 0, 3, 1] [2, 1, 0, 3] [2, 1, 3, 0] [2, 3, 0, 1] [2, 3, 1, 0]
[3, 0, 2, 1] [3, 1, 0, 2] [3, 1, 2, 0] [3, 2, 0, 1]
```

Note that `[0, 1, 3, 2]` is \$3\$-rich and NOT \$2\$-rich, because even though it contains a strictly increasing subsequence of length 2, it also contains a *longer* strictly increasing subsequence.

### The Challenge

Your challenge is to write a function which takes in an integer sequence S with some length \$L\$, and an integer \$1 \le N \le L\$, and returns the number of N-rich permutations of S.

This is code golf, so the shortest valid answer wins.

### Test cases

Each row is a sequence along with the expected output for all possible values of L. For example, the first row says that if your function is called `f`, then `f([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3) = 41`

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] => 1, 69, 41, 8, 1
[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5] => 4, 2612, 2064, 336, 24, 0, 0
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] => 5040, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4] => 8, 2976, 1864, 192, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: https://oeis.org/A008304 is related.

Comment: @Simd thanks for including that link! :)

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 9 bytes

```
#mȯ▲mLġ>P
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Xzn3xPpH0zbl@hxZaBfw////aEMdIx1jHRMd09j/RgA) or [Try the test lists with N=2](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6fm/CoqfG/cu6J9Y@mbcr1ObLQLuD///9G/6OjDXWMdIx1THRMY3XAbBAPwUeCUHljHaiO2FgA)

```
#mȯ▲mLġ>P
        P  # get all permutations of arg1
 m         # map over each permutation:
  ȯ        #   these 3 composed functions:
      ġ>   #   - group by pairwise greater-than
    mL     #   - get the length of each group
   ▲       #   - maximum
#          # how many times is arg2 present?
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>85</s> <s>79</s> 77 bytes

Misread the prompt at first and was returning the permutations themselves instead of the amount, whoops.

```ruby
->a,n{a.permutation.count{|r,*b|m=c=1;b.map{m=c if m<c=r<(r=_1)?c+1:1};m==n}}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XY9RToQwEIbfOcVk4wNot6Gwi-Bu8QSeQDdYsCgJsKQUjbKcxJdN1NN4gr2Nw5asxmaS_ul8_z_T90_Vpa_7j5zffXU6n4eHm3ksSN0L2khVdVroYlvTbNvVut8pcp7uKp5xtkppJZoeNRQ5VOuMq7WteMKc6-yCXbFhVXFeD8MUev_yVJQSHqVuLRBEAoezhLZNWWh7xuOZc0yTz6KEhA0WKARsRqmgbfEmTTenmShLWxBEHGQaUAQU59KS9YOZsz983zICHgGfwILAcgPm8BjGRhDhM94hAbaxJtTQJ8OIovICNvbcALXvByhRuFjG97-Mb-kuXEP9rdMk_8hO2xkHbuJFlxjPwnESi7xfm_nTDw)

```ruby
->a,n{                                 # Lambda definition
  a.permutation                        # Permutations
   .count{                             # Count instances that match the given condition
          |r,*b|                       #  Extract first element as r (pRevious element)
                m=c=1;                 #  Initialize variables
                                       #   (m = max subsequence length)
                                       #   (c = current subsequence length)
                b.map{                 #  Iterate over the rest of the permutation
                      c=r<(r=_1)?c+1:1 #   If prev. element < current, add 1 to c
                                       #    Otherwise, reset c to 1
                                       #   Also reset r here to save bytes
                      m=c if m<c       #   Set max if needed
                     };                #  End map call
          m==n}                        # Match if max == N
}                                      # End lambda
```

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 87 bytes

Expects `(n)(array)`.

```javascript
n=>g=(a,s,m,p)=>a.map((v,i)=>t+=g(a.filter(_=>i--),q=v>p?s+1:1,q<m?m:q,v),t=0)+a?t:m==n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVBdb4MwDHzvr/BjIgwl0LJCa3jar6hQFTHoMgHhS/x9Zsoktlkn5RzfySd/6VmPxWC6yW3tR7lUtLSUPkloHLHBTlKqvUZ3QsxouJkcegrtVaaeykE8KDWuK7GnOe2y0VGJwv7WZE3S4yxxIl86OpuShqhdrvcDwF0hBAghwgnhnCNsdTwCD6KYv/m9IKhdu8l3B2uZBZFaZ37EPAwjpkx8xo/xPzbj2T/5m@w3/uTaA@avXBwmiN94gbqsu1Qc7L784FV2eNfFp9BAKRS2HW1derVdj/Q62wPByHVWCQMOKCm05Fq@AQ)

#### Commented

```javascript
n =>                 // outer function taking n
g = (                // inner recursive function g taking:
  a,                 //   a[] = input array
  s,                 //   s = size of the strictly increasing sequence
  m,                 //   m = maximum size so far
  p                  //   p = previous value from the permutation
) =>                 //
a.map((v, i) =>      // for each value v at index i in a[]:
  t +=               //   add to t the result of ...
    g(               //     ... a recursive call to g:
      a.filter(_ =>  //       remove from a[]:
        i--          //         the i-th element
      ),             //
      q =            //       q = new value of s, defined as follows:
        v > p ?      //         if v is greater than p:
          s + 1      //           increment s
        :            //         else:
          1,         //           reset to 1
      q < m ? m : q, //       m = max(m, q)
      v              //       pass v as the previous value
    ),               //     end of recursive call
  t = 0              //   start with t = 0
)                    // end of map()
+ a ?                // if a[] is empty:
  t                  //   return t
:                    // else:
  m == n             //   return 1 if the maximum size is n
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `L`, 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
qæƑœØ^ḷG¹=
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPXElQzMlQTYlQzYlOTElQzUlOTMlQzMlOTglNUUlRTElQjglQjdHJUMyJUI5JTNEJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9JTVCMSUyQyUyMDIlMkMlMjAzJTJDJTIwNCUyQyUyMDUlNUQlMEEyJmZsYWdzPUw=)
or [verify all test cases](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#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)

##### Explanation

```python
qæƑœØ^ḷG¹=  # Implicit input
q           # All permutations of the first input
 æ          # Filtered by:
  Ƒ         #  All sublists of this list
   œØ^      #  Only keep strictly ascending ones
      ḷG    #  Get the maximum length
        ¹=  #  Equals the second input?
            # Implicit output of length
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), <del>62</del> 57 bytes

Port of [@chunes's Factor code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/264172/110802) in Mathematica.

Saved 5 bytes thanks to the comment of [@ZaMoC](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67961/zamoc)

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/BSsRAEETv@xUFgUWXgWDU0xpYEDwpLHgMQcaxkwwknTjdswbEb4@zOeVQhy6qX3cNVjsarHpnl5sDXnxQUbxPvVd41hFCFwq2T4MLZMVzCzeykIvqLwSJn0LfkdiRGCQWo/H8BZvkxsh69TBRGKKmK2kTPx0FWu1@5JZEt@wND50V9MStdihwuN015fJ8RVbnDe6UmfkjP77ZuXpds/lp/b6aTfaUFfu6Lsui3i8TSvzeGRQG9wYPBo9/x11TTTXy/BxS1eUf)

```mathematica
Count[Permutations@#,x_/;Max[Length/@Split[x,#<#2&]]==2]&
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBPS8QwEMXv/RQPFkSXQNmqF9eCoCiCwoLHUpZYp20gnazNFAXxs9ck/hc85JB5L7/3MoOWngYtptHzvL/EBbWGCe3EjRjHEAe/s0ag4elxIm4IhsPUcDOS9oY7@On@U/NYHmR38cH1l15Z42Vb46REUtJdYbHCKRYF9up1loXkK2IatRC0tdjROEyiYwUP1yKU/M4PEVH3KLH54ateVgqFwqHCkcLx6wf30vADdDiNm1gS6Rf9qaeR0tg67sjLP19Drz0scSc9itjhPPKq1EQl5Bb5Grf6ubp5d@Vn@LuKaKtrlCWKGnm@GcMu5/kN)

```mathematica
(* Define function to split a sequence into increasing subsequences *)
SplitIncreasing[list_] := Split[list, #1 < #2 &];

(* Generate all permutations of the sequence *)
perms = Permutations[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}];

(* Find and count the permutations where the longest increasing subsequence has length 2 *)
Count[perms, perm_ /; Max[Length /@ SplitIncreasing[perm]] == 2] //Print
```

Comment: you can make a function for [57 bytes](https://tio.run/##TY/BSsRAEETv@xUFgUWXgWDU0xpYEDwpLHgMQcaxkwwknTjdswbEb4@zOeVQhy6qX3cNVjsarHpnl5sDXnxQUbxPvVd41hFCFwq2T4MLZMVzCzeykIvqLwSJn0LfkdiRGCQWo/H8BZvkxsh69TBRGKKmK2kTPx0FWu1@5JZEt@wND50V9MStdihwuN015fJ8RVbnDe6UmfkjP77ZuXpds/lp/b6aTfaUFfu6Lsui3i8TSvzeGRQG9wYPBo9/x11TTTXy/BxS1eUf "Wolfram Language (Mathematica) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 126 bytes

*-19 bytes thanks to @ValueInk and @TheThonnu*

*+2 bytes, index was off by one*

```python
lambda l,i:sum(i==1+max(sum(b)for(_,b)in groupby(a>b for(a,b)in zip(p[1:],p)))for p in permutations(l))
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBBasMwEKRXv2LJSWo2YNmJmwScj6ShyImdiFqWUGRoeuhHejGU9k_ta7qKCk0CC7szmtlZ9P5lT_5guuGjKR8_e99M5t9vrdTVTkKLannsNVNlKcZavrAAKt4Yx56w4qqDvTO9rU5MrioItIz0q7LMrsVyg5bzoAcLRNva6d5Lr0x3ZC3nSeOMBuVr541pj6C0Nc7fxyt-7opd3cD2UG-fWYuaLxMIGaAg7HKy29dMYFt3tGoszs9gneo8qRWOoFzBCFkTEC9LvVYTseHEjzByPEni8rVAyBByhCnCbIMBFwtC1OcI5LoWRu2_nFpWiPCQFjTneUEjDSnVlfe2yDtLp2lUXtZtYn7W_91ILroqWzxQjJiHRLHILqzx-4Yh9l8)

Comment: Some <strike>semi-colons</strike> `lambda` and you can save a few bytes!

Comment: [133 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLasMwEKVbn2LwSgpT8CdxE4NzEdcLObETEcsSigxN9z1FN4HS3qk9TUdRoUlgYH7vzXvS-5c5ub0ezx999fw5uf5x-f02CNVuBQwoy-OkmKwqJV5YLWZDN7J61ja815YJbLkcYWf1ZNoTrdctXM1fpWGmTssGDW_4hQIGaGE6qyYnnNTjkQ2cR73VCqTrrNN6OIJURls3C2Z-HrJt18Nm320ObEDFywi8Ckjwt6wYdx1L0BujU34JxsrREVZiDNUaYmS97zi9opYNp2mMYcKjKByuU4QMIUeYIywa9H2xoo7yEiFt-C0wYP_hlLIi9YukoDrPCyqpSChuuPdB3EUyTwLyOu4V8wv-zyOxyFW2eiKZdOkV01V2RQ1fdz6H_As)

Comment: Some of these functions can take list comprehensions directly, dropping @TheThonnu's suggestion down to [130 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLasMwEKVbn2LISgpT8CdxHYNzEdcLObETUcsSsgxNl71GN4HS3qk9TUdVoUlgYGbevDdvpLdPc3JHPZ7f--rxY3b9ffH1OgjV7gUMKMtpVkxWlRLPTCyHbmT1sm14ry0T2HI5wsHq2bQnJrYtXMAv0jBTJ2WDhnPPBwMEm86q2Qkn9TixgfOot1qBdJ11Wg8TSGW0dbAMl3zfpfuuh92x2z2xARUvI_AmIMEvs2I8dCxGfxbt8kMwVo6OuBIXUG1hgaz3Hacn1LLhhC4wIDyKwuI6QUgRMoQVwrpB3-cb6igXCEnDr4mB-0-nlOaJH8Q51VmWU0lFTHGlvQ3SruNVHJiXceuY_fL_biQVXZVuHsgmKbxjskkvpOHrzueQfwA)

Comment: @ValueInk you've got a redundant space - [129 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=XVBLasMwEKVbn2LISgpT8CdxHYNzEdcLObETUcsSsgxNdz1HN4HS3qk9TUdVoUlgYGbevDdvpLdPc3JHPZ7f--rxY3b9ffH1OgjV7gUMKMtpVkxWlRLPTCyHbmT1sm14ry0T2HI5wsHq2bQnJrYtXMAv0jBTJ2WDhnPPBwMEm86q2Qkn9TixgfOot1qBdJ11Wg8TSGW0dctwyPdduu962B273RMbUPEyAu8BEvwuK8ZDx2L0V9EqPwRj5eiIK3EB1RYWyHrfcXpBLRtO6AIDwqMoLK4ThBQhQ1ghrBv0fb6hjnKBkDT8mhi4_3RKaZ74QZxTnWU5lVTEFFfa2yDtOl7FgXkZt47ZL__vRlLRVenmgWySwjsmm_RCGr7ufA75Bw)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.combinatorics`, <s>83</s> 72 bytes

```
[ <permutations> [ [ < ] monotonic-split longest length = ] with count ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PU67CsJAEOzzFfMDCRgVxFerNjZiJRbnsYmHl714t0FE_BKbNOaf_BsPA7LF7MwuM_PqCqXF-fZz2u8229UUlZJzpl11MqziwejwkxBqa0QMl1nl2IljoxHo2hBrCqg9idxrb1hwIc9kMUuSHA8MkGOIEcZ4vhsp0slnfcC8Jl81osQ4Dksc4sxxxN85_aXBOi4pRCQuY4VFfLmZuGjXxJxj79dpZS2ynrRtj18)

- `<permutations> [ ... ] with count` Count permutations of the input sequence using `[ ... ]` (a predicate quotation/lambda).
- `[ < ] monotonic-split` Split into increasing subsequences.
- `longest length` Get the length of the longest one.
- `=` Is this equal to the numeric input?

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
Œ!ẆIRẠƊƇẈṀƲ€ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHu9o8gx7uWnCs61j7w10dD3c2HNv0qGnNke7/h5cD6cj/XP@jDXWMdIx1THRMY3UUgBwFIzAyBiMTHQWYMDpCqDYGC0AYJrH/jQA)

-1 byte thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)!

Footer runs each sequence test case over a provided \$N\$

## [Jelly (fork)](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/jellylanguage), 10 bytes

```
Ẇ<ɲƇẈṀƲÐ!ċ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hrjabk5uOtT/c1fFwZ8OxTYcnKB7p/n94@aOmNZH/uf5HG@oY6RjrmOiYxuooADkKRmBkDEYmOgowYXSEUG0MFoAwTGL/GwEA) (or, rather, don't as it isn't implemented on TIO)

### How they work

```
Œ!ẆIRẠƊƇẈṀƲ€ċ - Main link. Takes S on the left, N on the right
Œ!            - All permutations of S
          Ʋ€  - Over each permutation P:
  Ẇ           -   All contiguous sublists
      ƊƇ      -   Filter sublists on:
   I          -     Increments
     Ạ        -     all
    R         -     have a non-zero range
        Ẉ     -   Lengths
         Ṁ    -   Maximum
            ċ - Count N
```

```
Ẇ<ɲƇẈṀƲÐ!ċ - Main link. Takes S on the left and N on the right
      ƲÐ!  - Over the permutations of S:
Ẇ          -   Contiguous sublists
   Ƈ       -   Keep those such that:
  ɲ        -     All neighbours are:
 <         -       In ascending order
    ẈṀ     -   Maximum length
         ċ - Count N
```

Comment: Snap, well almost. Although you beat me to it, when I was thinking about trying to get mine down to 12 I thought of the same filter but with `R` rather than `>0`.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Very nice, didn't think `Ạ` would catch that with `R`!

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Œ!Ẇ<ƝẠ$ƇṪLƲ€ċ
```

A dyadic Link that accepts the list of elements, \$L\$, on the left and the number, \$n\$, on the right and yields the count of \$n\$-rich permutations of \$L\$.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHu9psjs19uGuByrH2hztX@Rzb9KhpzZHu////RxvqKBiBkTEYmegomMb@NwUA)**

Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///oJMWHu9psjs19uGuByrH2hztX@Rzb9Khpzf/D7Ue6H21c56X5/390tKGOgpGOgrGOgomOgmmsDpcCVAQiiCaOjpDUG4NFoEYBxWMB) (count, `ċ`, has been moved out to the footer to make it more efficient, and so finish within the TIO timeout).

#### How?

```
Œ!Ẇ<ƝẠ$ƇṪLƲ€ċ - Link: L, n
Œ!            - all permutations of {L}
           €  - for each:
          Ʋ   -   last four links as a monad:
  Ẇ           -     sublists (from shortest to longest)
       Ƈ      -     filter keep those for which:
      $       -       last two links as a monad:
    Ɲ         -         for neighbouring pairs:
   <          -           less than?
     Ạ        -         all?
        Ṫ     -     tail
         L    -     length
            ċ - count occurrences of {n}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata) + `-n`, 10 bytes

```
↕∆±ĉᵐ∑çṀ→=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHFNtJJurpKOgpJunlLsgqWlJWm6FjsftU191NF2aOORzodbJzzqmHh4-cOdDY_aJtkuKU5KLoaqWnCLcX-0oY6RjrGOiY5prIIhFzLPCIVnjMIzQeGZQnggPqpJSCJGGCLGGCImGCKYJpthiJiDRJAg1HYUESMMEWMMERMMEVMMETMMEXNYSEDDAykU4SJGGCLGGCImGCKmGCJmGCLmkIgEAA)

```
↕∆±ĉᵐ∑çṀ→=
↕           Find a permutation of the first input
 ∆          Delta
  ±         Sign
   ĉ        Split into runs of equal elements
    ᵐ∑      Sum each run
      ç     Prepend 0 to handle the case with no nonnegative runs
       Ṁ    Maximum
        →   Increment
         =  Check if equal to the second input
```

`-n` counts the number of solutions.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
œʒü‹γOà-}g
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9vc2FiaWX//8WTypLDvOKAuc6zT8OgLX1n//9bMSwyLDMsNCw1XQoz) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9WeWjlkcayQ@vslRQS81IUlOwrgaxHbZNArNBD6/4fnXxq0uE9jxp2ntvsf3hBRLFubfp/nf/R0YY6RjrGOiY6prE6YDaIh@AjQai8sQ5UR2wsAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
œ         # Push all permutations of the first (implicit) input-list
 ʒ        # Filter it by:
  ü       #  For each overlapping pair:
   ‹      #   Check whether the first is smaller than the second
    γ     #  Group the 0s and 1s into adjacent equal groups
     O    #  Sum each inner group
      à   #  Pop and push the maximum
       -  #  Subtract it from the second (implicit) input-integer
          #  (only 1 is truthy in 05AB1E)
 }g       # After the filter: pop and push the length
          # (which is output implicitly as result)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 100 bytes

```arturo
$=>[n:&enumerate permutate&'x[i:0n=1+??max
map select chunk chop x'y['i+1y<x\[i]]=>sorted?=>size 0]]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?WvI33K)

```
$=>[                        ; a function where successive inputs are assigned to &
    n:&                     ; assign first input (number) to n
    enumerate permutate&'x[ ; count each permutation x of input seq
        i:0                 ; assign 0 to i
        n=1+                ; does n equal 1 plus
        ?? ... 0            ; if ... is null, evaluate to 0, else to ...
        max                 ; maximum value of
        map...=>size        ; lengths of
        select...=>sorted?  ; sorted blocks of
        chunk chop x'y[     ; split x-sans-last-elt into contiguous blocks by...
            '1+1            ; increment i in place
            y<x\[i]         ; is y less than x[i]? (is it increasing?)
        ]                   ; end chunk
    ]                       ; end enumerate
]                           ; end function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `l`, 71 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 8.875 bytes

```
Ṗ'ÞS~Þ⇧@G⁰=
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJsPUIiLCIiLCLhuZYnw55TfsOe4oenQEfigbA9IiwiIiwiWzEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDEsIDFdXG4yIl0=)

### Explained

```
Ṗ'ÞS~Þ⇧@G⁰=­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁤​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁡⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢⁢​‎‏​⁢⁠⁡‌­
Ṗ'           # ‎⁡Filter permutations where:
  ÞS         # ‎⁢  All sublists
    ~Þ⇧      # ‎⁣  that are strictly increasing
       @G    # ‎⁤  has maximum sublist length
         ⁰=  # ‎⁢⁡  equals N
# ‎⁢⁢The l flag gets the length of all the permutations.
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Comment: [-1 bit](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJzPSIsIiIsIuG5lsabw55TfsOe4oenQEfigbA9IiwiIiwiWzEsMiwzLDQsNV1cbjIiXQ==)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 45 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＩ№ＥυＬ⌈⪪⭆Φιμ‹§θλ§θ§ιμ0⊖η
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TU9LasMwEN33FINXI1CgXyhkFVoKhQYMXhotXEexRSQ50Ugld-kmi5b2DL1JL9BzdKSkUDGS3nvz9Aa9fvZjF_qps4fDe4rr2e33T51oxCShVWJ-tp4C4E7AgsgMHpvkcNltcztfS-MTFWEnwQsJG961ZW3D750SvCQkzqmD8RHvOuJjSgxPKU_aD3FktjeOs5utNRGbyO4hOx6MjTqgkeBENhPhIj76ld7niZa1f_QPFneZXJ1XR3Cv-6Cd9lGvcMzS_I2eezr9-aOtZi-2Ul9teyHhstRVqWsJN4q5Ohp_AQ) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

Generate all of the permutations from `0` to `L-1`. This is based on my answer to [1 to N column and row sums](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/254768/) but uses the indices of the input rather than an explicit range.

```
Ｉ№ＥυＬ⌈⪪⭆Φιμ‹§θλ§θ§ιμ0⊖η
```

For each permutation, create a binary string representing strictly increasing consecutive values of the input array, then split that string on `0`s and take the length of the longest resulting contiguous substring of `1`s. Count the number for which that is `N-1`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 189 bytes

```
f(L,n)=∑_{k=0}^{l^l-1}0^{(I.unique.length-l)^2+([S.length0^{0^{max(0,S[2...]-S)}.total}forb=[1...l],d=[0...l]].max-n)^2}
l=L.length
I=mod(floor(kl/l^{[1...l]}),l)+1
S=L[I][b...min(l,b+d)]
```

[Try It On Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/b3vvd7mewq)

[Try It On Desmos! - Prettified](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ww0mszmxi4)

Probably some of the most horrendous and inefficient Desmos code I have ever written, but at least it gets the job done (disregarding runtime lmao). It is so inefficient that I don't think it can even run a list of length 7 any time soon.

I might write a longer explanation later, but the gist of it is that I iterate through all base-\$l\$ numbers of length \$l\$ where \$l\$ is the length of the input list \$L\$, then check if the resulting digits form a valid permutation of \$0,\ldots,l-1\$, then add \$1\$ to the digits because of 1-indexing. This digit list is then used to permute \$L\$. Then for each permutation I check for the "richness" by further iterating through all sublists of the permutation. Finally with that, I can count the number of permutations that are "\$n\$-rich".

Comment: I absolutely adore Desmos. Thank you for this wonderful answer.

Comment: @EphraimRuttenberg Thanks for such a nice comment! I love "code golfing" in Desmos (well, Desmos isn't really code per se, but it is considered a programming language here), and I have written a bunch of other Desmos answers too, some of which I consider even more complex than what is going on in this answer.

Comment: Also I don't know if you are interested at all in golfing in Desmos, but it's not that hard to learn. Once you learn how to golf the \$\LaTeX\$ syntax you are already half way there!

Comment: Do you have a resource or comprehensive documentation for writing stuff like this? Information on what Desmos has to offer is kind of scarce.

Comment: @EphraimRuttenberg Honestly, since Desmos code golfing is very niche, there aren't that many resources that go over Desmos golfing specifically, though you can look at the [Tips for Golfing in Desmos](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/230100/tips-for-code-golfing-in-desmos) page as a sort of starting point. I mainly just learned this from years of Desmos experience and experimenting with random stuff I see on other peoples' creations.

Comment: There are also unofficial documentation from other people, like https://desmosgraphunofficial.wordpress.com/, as there are many undocumented features in Desmos that many people starting out learning Desmos may find useful.

Comment: You could try golfing some simple challenges in Desmos and see how you do, then I can give you some tips on your answers if you want.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 131 bytes

```perl
sub{($r,%s)=pop;$"=",";0+grep{my($l,$f,$m);$m+=($l=$_>$f?$l+1:1)>$m,$f=$_ for@_[/./g];$m==$r}grep!/(.).*\1/,glob"{@{[0..$#_]}}"x@_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZHRbpswFIavx1P8c90FGo/gpGFNkFPuJzU3vUsj1LQmRQNMCdk6MZ49OyZVm/VyliWOv3O@HwsqXefTA0/VYbfftC6vxfnOU5WpIs4UEywKhttaV23x2@W54KnghRfxYqjoqHiy4Ok1z4dyLr0FL6hPDKmp42Q18kfbNY0qxevOZnweub7nX9zJkdjmZsPauF0Fvs/PknXXsZc46Q6Rw/8oGTmU4DorACspMBaYCFwKTNc4LrUA8XBGlJ5XAhL/rLU4lY/@WwTJVIxDaVtBSPVkElJJRUD7g0za@xV6mV43nn0jQ15ZWc7GR9G6p/LH3cvT4DJ4Gz/xXq@Ns19ZnqPJCm32DUyJ22wp8GCKQpd0Jna/MT818qzUaAzqfYnmKdv1wPFax@bYf5WVlYj1S@WpmCfRK0a8NY0q7it84akb90M88ez3830Ew578x3BVZ2WTsvOv4Q4gum/m6NvUozvoh0Y/EqGSAKXO@@y7kgnnE7OYQT@DWchwjYH5McAcg5vlLZbfB5HTHf4C)

Answer (score 0):

## [sclin](https://github.com/molarmanful/sclin), 48 bytes

```
perm";"map = +/
2%`",_ <"map"="pack0"+/ |"fold1+
```

[Try it here!](https://replit.com/@molarmanful/try-sclin) Takes number first, then sequence.

For testing purposes:

```
3 [1 2 3 4 5] ;
perm";"map = +/
2%`",_ <"map"="pack0"+/ |"fold1+
```

### Explanation

Prettified code:

```
perm \; map = +/
2%` ( ,_ < ) map \= pack 0 ( +/ | ) fold 1+
```

Assuming number *n* and sequence *s*.

- `perm \; map` map over each permutation of *s*...

  - `` 2%` ( ,_ < ) map `` pairwise map with "less than" to get booleans indicating increases
  - `\= pack` group consecutive runs of booleans
  - `0 ( +/ | ) fold 1+` get maximum sum + 1

    - sum implicitly converts true to 1 and false to 0
- `= +/` vectorized equals to *n*, sum

  - i.e. count occurrences of *n*