# Pseudo-Quantum Bogosort

Tags: code-golf, sorting

### Pseudo-Quantum Bogosort

Quantum Bogosort is as follows:

1. Quantumly randomise the list, such that there is no way of knowing what order the list is in until it is observed. This will divide the universe into O(n!) universes; however, the division has no cost, as it happens constantly anyway.
2. If the list is not sorted, destroy the universe. (This operation is left as an exercise to the reader.)
3. All remaining universes contain lists which are sorted.

[Source](http://wiki.c2.com/?QuantumBogoSort)

Given that we cannot destroy the universe, the next best thing is to destroy a thread!

The challenge is as follows:
Make a new thread/branch for each possible permutation of a list and if the list is not sorted, destroy the thread/branch (or just dont output it)

### Rules

Input is a list of length 4 or less

Output should be the randomized list for each thread or branch that successfully sorted it. Destroying/exiting the thread or branch is optional, but funny.

If there is a repeated number, output list duplicates.

This is standard code-golf

Test cases:

```
[1,4,2,9] -> [1,2,4,9]
[3,1,1,9] -> [1,1,3,9] and [1,1,3,9]
[3,1,1,3] -> [1,1,3,3] [1,1,3,3] [1,1,3,3] [1,1,3,3]
```

Comment: why am I like this

Comment: This is a funny idea but it seems like an [unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11197/should-we-disallow-non-observable-requirements) :o

Comment: ok made it optional

Comment: No I mean like, implementing a specific algorithm at all is unobservable. this might as well just be a dupe of [sort a list](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/77836/sort-an-integer-list). Unless I'm misunderstanding something about unobservable requirements and the nature of the challenge...

Comment: I think the fact that one input can have multiple outputs via multithreading makes this different enough, especially since there is precedent with other multithreading challenges

Comment: @thejonymyster I agree with Pacmanboss256 - this shouldn't be closed as a dupe of sort a list.

Comment: Suggest test case: [3,3,1,1].  There should be 4 (identical) outputs (corresponding to forks that sort in orders [3,4,1,2], [4,3,1,2], [3,4,2,1], and [4,3,2,1].

Comment: Dominic's two answers don't seem to use threading. Is this ok? (See [my comment](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264987/pseudo-quantum-bogosort/264990#comment578723_264989) on his Husk answer)

Comment: May we create only the desired universes? (Comes back to being observable requirements really.)

Comment: as long as youre generating all permutations "in parallel" and keeping the sorted ones rather than just sorting a list i think its fine

Comment: @jonathanallan, no that defeats the point of the question

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 - from your response below my Husk answer, I still can't tell whether you're insisting on the unobservable requirement to use 'branches' (whatever they are) or parallel threading (whatever that is).

Comment: By branches I was referring to any fork in the code that is created for each permutation

Comment: I left this in sandbox for a week with no complaints btw

Comment: That [doesn't](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21961/36398) change the fact that "Make a new thread/branch..." is an unobservable requirement

Comment: @LuisMendo How is spawning threads unobservable? Doing specific work on them sure, but spawning them and then killing them is definitely observable

Comment: @ATaco Is it? How can that be observed? Note that by "observe" we mean [when the program is treated as a black box](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/36398)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 77 bytes

```python
lambda l:[x for x in permutations(l)if[*x]==sorted(x)]
from itertools import*
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vweI025ilpSVpuhY3fXMSc5NSEhVyrKIrFNLyixQqFDLzFApSi3JLSxJLMvPzijVyNDPTorUqYm1ti_OLSlJTNCo0Y7nSivJzFTJLUotK8vNzihUycwuAcloQQzcXFGXmlWikaUQb6xjrGOoYxmpqQmQWLIDQAA)

Comment: Is destroying the threads unreasonable because I'm fine with removing that part

Comment: @Pacmanboss256 yeah, it probably is unreasonable.

Comment: The second version seems wrong: there should be 4 outputs for an input of [3,3,1,1].

Comment: @DominicvanEssen fixed, thanks

Answer (score 2):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
fS=OP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/Py3Y1j/g////0YY6hjpGOsY6JjomsQA)

Quite closely follows the description.

```
    P  # Make a list with an element for each possible permutation of the input list
f      # Destroy (or just don't output) any element that doesn't satisfy: 
 S=O   #   it's sorted
```

Comment: It looks like there's no threading here: the `f` seems to just be a "filter". I'll ask OP whether this is ok, as it seems like this would be a nice challenge without all the threading stuff.

Comment: @MTN - ```f``` is indeed ```filter```.  I have no idea whether this is implemented by the Husk interpreter by threading or otherwise, and I have no way to find out.  The output would be identical either way.

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't look like it uses threading (https://github.com/barbuz/Husk/blob/master/Builtins.hs#L412). Anyway, let's wait for clarification from OP.

Comment: yeah i edited the original post to allow branches, I think the idea is to generate all the lists "in parallel" and only output the sorted variants,

Comment: @MTN that is only _an_ implementation of Husk though. That is a part of the reason unobservable requirements are considered bad. The other is that they basically prescribe the answer, which is pretty dull.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I agree - I would prefer it if the threading thing was dropped.

Answer (score 2):

## [Nekomata](https://github.com/AlephAlpha/Nekomata), <s>3</s> 4 bytes

*Edit: +1 byte to fix (unobservable) mechanism-of-action, thanks to [alephalpha](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/264987/pseudo-quantum-bogosort/264990?noredirect=1#comment578782_264990).*

```
↕:o=
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m70iLzU7PzexJHHBgqWlJWm6FssetU21yrddUpyUXAwVWrAy2lDHUMdIxygWIgAA)

Nekomata seems well-suited for this.
Default behaviour is to output all successful forks.

```
↕      # non-deterministically choose a permutation of the input list
 :     # duplicate it
  o=   # keep one duplicate if it's equal to the other, sorted
```

Comment: Sorry, I think it should be `↕:o=`. Nekomata is stack-based. `↕=` finds a permutation that is equal to the input list, and `o` sorts it. Pseudo-quantum bogosort is an [unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11197/9288) though.

Comment: @alephalpha - Ah!  Thanks for the explanation!  Indeed, the unobservability made it difficult for me to be sure that the code was really doing what I wanted, of course.  Perhaps this can serve as a genuine example of why unobservable requirements are a bad thing...

Comment: @alephalpha - I've linked your comment: please don't delete it!

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org) + `math.combinatorics`, 49 bytes

```
[ <permutations> [ dup sort = ] parallel-filter ]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TUw5DsIwEOzzivkAkaI0iKtFNDSIKkphjAMWztpar4sI8RKaNORP-Q0RadAUoznfQ6O0eO7H6nw6HPcrtEruufbtxZKaAqsjHobJOETPYukG7UknZkO6-ytGBDYiXWBLgnWWPVGimFDi9UnSLJZjUWETDLdJlFhPcYcK1xR-x9iiRlCsnDNu0VgnhlHPw0FPLvJZ9P3MXw)

`parallel-filter` is a version of `filter` that spawns cooperative threads to handle each iteration.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3.8+](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 75 bytes

```python
lambda a:filter(min(p:=[*permutations(a)]).__eq__,p)
from itertools import*
```

An unnamed function that accepts a tuple and returns a generator.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY3NCoMwEITvPsXiKZGlVG1BBfsiVSSlhgbMT@P2UIrPnia1O4f9Zlhm3Zse1tSN80H2Q1iEvt0FiE6qhWbPtDLMdf21cLPXLxKkrFmZ4CM/TNP8nCZ0PJPealDxnKxdVlDaWU9FkNYDzSuBMsBYhTWWeOIILEGJbcIznqLOCVts8binDf6UsMIqrRJ3U@4mlv39ntSxvOa8yyCO88oQk/knPd@gv8DnWkiWHB@3weQ8pLPwBQ)**

#### How?

`a` is the input tuple. `p` is initialised to a list of all permutations of `a`. A condition of being equal to the minimal permutation is then used to create a filter object.

---

Also, non-conforming but interesting at **62 bytes**:

```python
lambda a:8**sum(a.count(v)**7-1for v in{*a})%66%26*[sorted(a)]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY7dCoMwDIXv9xRBENqSjVWnU8G9iHrRTcuEWUWrMMRn71pdzsX58kOS4avfvQqTYTQyL81HdM9agMgSxqa5I@Ly6melyUIZu5@57EdYoFUrExv149gPYlZM/aibmghaGdfXzaTtCJAiwBA53iqEwgHH1GGEN6vIYYopXo9qgrscBhg44wfvxtHu@udHJbS7w4pmJ7AxjK39UXqru71B/oBVEsd0K5VHjfkB)

The number of repeats of the sorted list needs to be \$\prod_{m \in \text{multiplicities}} m!\$, e.g. `[5,4,5,5]` has multiplicities `[3,1]` and \$3!1!=6\$.

But that's going to cost a lot of bytes. However, since the input has a length of at most four there are only twelve cases to handle by multiplicity, so I thought a hash might be golfier, so I had a play and came up with:

| multiplicities | **7-1 | sum | 8**sum%66%26 == required length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [] | [] | 0 | 1 |
| [1] | [0] | 0 | 1 |
| [2] | [127] | 127 | 2 |
| [3] | [2187] | 2187 | 6 |
| [4] | [16383] | 16383 | 24 |
| [1,1] | [0,0] | 0 | 1 |
| [1,2] | [0,127] | 127 | 2 |
| [1,3] | [0,2187] | 2187 | 6 |
| [2,2] | [127,127] | 254 | 4 |
| [1,1,1] | [0,0,0] | 0 | 1 |
| [1,1,2] | [0,0,127] | 127 | 2 |
| [1,1,1,1] | [0,0,0,0] | 0 | 1 |

...it's certainly shorter than this, more logical, shortcut for lists of length at most four (71):

```python
lambda a:(sum((c:=a.count(v))*~-c*-~(c>3)for v in{*a})or 1)*[sorted(a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 40 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υＦυＵＭι§θκＥΦυ⁼ι⌊υ⭆¹ι
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NU_BCsIwDL37FWWnFrrD8KLsJKLgQRh4HD3UqVtZ27m1Ef_Fyw6Kgl_gp_g3plMTQuDlvZfk8igq2RWN1H1_A3-IJ-9XBq6iwEkuWDo6NB2hLSMz51Rp6QYMXctjGIe2VhbcALScWMZJjZVpxGrUG8EwOIG_D7CgmjfGSLujipOZX9nd_hzUNUNW1inrB7-l0n7fhT2LFqR2gY3blMEDYHDdeCSXgZtwohBKr25buN8b9zyKTzoSzzwf8wRzKsR38gE) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦⟧Ｆθ≔ΣＥυＥ⁻Ｅθνκ⁺κ⟦μ⟧υ
```

Generate all of the permutations of the indices of the input. This is taken from my answer to [Count N-Rich Permutations of an Integer Sequence](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/264166/). I use the indices because they're unique and it makes it easier to generate the permutations.

```
ＦυＵＭι§θκ
```

Map each index to the actual value from the input list.

```
ＥΦυ⁼ι⌊υ⭆¹ι
```

Pretty print those that equal the minimum i.e. sorted value.